# Launch Another jar File

Tags: java

I am writing a program the requires a be able to launch other jar files. On Microsoft Windows, I have found that the following works:

```
try
{
   Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process process = runtime.exec("java -Djava.ext.dirs=lib -Djava.library.path=lib mainPrgm");
}catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Launch failed.");}
```

The problem that I have is that this needs to work on both Linux and Mac OS X as well, and I am not sure that it will and cannot test it myself. If it cannot work by itself, can someone explain to me how I could get it to work?

Comment: why can't you install simple VM for testing ?

Comment: @Mzf For Linux, that's exactly what I did. Mac OS X is a different story since I have a PC and therefore cannot install OS X.